# Non-busy blocking Queue Implementation in C

Tags: c, locking, queue, posix, ibm-midrange

I am trying to implement a queue in C that causes a process to non-busy wait until there is an element in the queue to consume. I have tried two different things to try to achieve this.

The first problem I have is if the enqueue/dequeue operations have **if** conditionals to check the bounds( **if**(q->count == QUEUESIZE) ), the call to sem_wait will return immediately because no other process has obtained a lock.

If I change the conditional to **while**(q->count == QUEUESIZE), I believe the consumer process will 'busy wait' until the semaphore is posted by the producer process, which is not my goal of the implementation, and through testing, I've found that the consumer process will not acquire the lock and continue.

I think that I am close, but I can't seem to figure out how to work around these issues. I have thought about adding condition variables or pthread_mutex, but wanted to exhaust the semaphore options before adding in additional complexity.

```
#define QUEUESIZE 48

typedef struct 
{           
    char q[QUEUESIZE+1][150];
    int first;                      
    int last;                       
    int count;                      
    sem_t *lock;                    
} Queue;


init_queue(Queue *q, sem_t *l)
{
    q->first = 0;
    q->last = QUEUESIZE-1;
    q->count = 0;
    q->lock = l;
}

enqueue(Queue *q, char x[150])
{
    while(q->count == QUEUESIZE)
        sem_wait(q->lock);

    if (q->count == 0)
    {
        if (sem_post(q->lock) == -1)
        {
            printf("Thread failed to unlock semaphore\n");
        }
    }       
    q->last = (q->last+1) % QUEUESIZE;
    strcpy(q->q[ q->last ],x);    
    q->count = q->count + 1;
}

dequeue(Queue *q,char *ptr)
{
    char x[150];
    while(q->count == 0)
        sem_wait(q->lock);

    if (q->count == QUEUESIZE) 
    {
        if (sem_post(q->lock) == -1)
        {
            printf("Thread failed to unlock semaphore\n");
        }
    }   
    strcpy(ptr,q->q[ q->first]);
    q->first = (q->first+1) % QUEUESIZE;
    q->count = q->count - 1;
}
```

Comment: Which operating system? Linux? (POSIX?)

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant Actually using IBM i (AS/400), but it supports the POSIX interfaces similarly to *nix.

Comment: I changed the tags, maybe more people will check in now.

Comment: Srsly? Your programming under OS/400? Dude, that platform is *amazing*! And as you eluded to in your question, a condvar and mutex would make this pretty trivial. Your while statement in `dequeue` looks a little odd. `sen_wait` is supposed to block if the queue is counter is zero. If anything, you should work on that and perhaps check the retval while there.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I'm not sure if this should be noted, but the semaphore is being initialized as such: sem_init(queue_lock,1,1); Since the dequeue gets called by a process before the enqueue does, it takes the 1 spot the semaphore has and decrements the semaphore to 0.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that? Ideally the resource count on your semaphore always reflects the queue-count. Unless the queue itself starts out with an initial occupant as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig - The reason I only initialize to 1 is because there is only 1 process that will ever try to dequeue from the queue, rather than having multiple consumers.

Comment: Ok, the you may need to review [`sem_init()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init), because the second parameter should be zero (0) if only one process will be using the semaphore,and the *third* parameter should reflect the initial count (which for an empty queue should also be zero). Unless I'm totally not reading your code and comments right. In other words, a single-process, multi-thread semaphore should use `sem_init(&lock, 0, 0)` for an initial empty queue. Personally I find this algorithm easier with a cv+mutex, and you're going to likely need a mtx anyway.

Comment: Why don't you set two semaphores?
One with the amount of free entries and one with the amount of written entries.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I have changed the initialization of the semaphore to sem_init(&lock,1,0) -> the semaphore will be used by 2 processes, and the initial amount of entries on the queue is 0. I want to use the semaphore to non-busy block the enqueue/dequeue operations when the current queue capacity is at the bounds (0 entries - maximum entries)

Comment: @mattwolfe16 ok, now I understand. it is *not* single-process, but one process is exclusively dequeueing. got it. You're still going to need a mutex or atomic increment/decrement functions for accessing your first/last members safely.

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens - I took your suggestion and added in a second semaphore. Works great now. Much appreciated everyone for your input.

Comment: @mattwolfe16 your welcome.
Could you add your answer to the problem?

Comment: Can you add the appropriate as400 or OS400 or i5os or whichever ones are defined here at SO, please? That will help others searching for solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here is my solution.

```
#define QUEUESIZE 50

typedef struct 
{           
    char q[QUEUESIZE][150];
    int first;                      
    int last;                       
    int count;                      
    sem_t *full;
    sem_t *empty;
    sem_t *excl;

} Queue;


void init_queue(Queue *q, sem_t *f,sem_t *e, sem_t *ee,)
{
    q->first = 0;
    q->last = QUEUESIZE-1;
    q->count = 0;
    q->full = f;
    q->empty = e;
    q->excl = ee; 
}

void enqueue(Queue *q, char x[150])
{
    sem_wait(q->empty);
    sem_wait(q->excl);

    q->last = (q->last+1) % QUEUESIZE;
    strcpy(q->q[ q->last ],x);    
    q->count = q->count + 1;

    sem_post(q->excl);
    sem_post(q->full);
}

void dequeue(Queue *q,char *ptr)
{
    sem_wait(q->full);
    sem_wait(q->excl);

    strcpy(ptr,q->q[ q->first]);
    q->first = (q->first+1) % QUEUESIZE;
    q->count = q->count - 1;

    sem_post(q->excl);
    sem_post(q->empty);
}
```

I initialize the semaphores as follows:

```
sem_init(full,1,0);
sem_init(empty,1,49);
sem_init(dequeue_excl,1,1);
sem_init(enqueue_excl,1,1);
```

Comment: mhhh i think there could be a race condition with `q->count` and if you have more then 2 process (threads) there could be a race condition with `q->first` and `q->last`.

Answer (score 0):

As you recognize in your example using semaphores, you need some support from your operating system to accomplish this. If you are on an operating system that supports POSIX Message Queues, you can just rely on that. Otherwise, you can use pthread condition variables as the basis for your implementation.

The trick is, you need two condition variables to cover the full and empty wait states. The implementation is simple, but difficult to cover corner cases and even harder to test well.

I've prepared an example which is the time-honored Apache apr_queue implementation but with the dependencies stripped down to only pthreads: https://github.com/chrismerck/rpa_queue