# is it reasonable/sensible to create many thread condition variables and mutexes?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have a program with 1+N threads, and N FIFO queues, like: FIFO_queue_t* fifo_queque[N].
one thread is responsible for filling these N FIFO queues.
And each of the other threads is related to 1 FIFO queue.

For each of the other thread i , it keeps on checking whether its FIFO queue fifo_queue[i], if it is not empty, they fetch all the elements from the fifo_queue and make the fifo_queue empty again.

now the problem is how to do the checking(or polling if you prefer). One way is

```
  for(;;)
  {
     if(fifo_queue[i] != NULL)
     {
          fetch_all_element();
      }
   }
```

in this way, it may be very CPU-consuming?
so an alternative approach is to use pthread_cond_t variable,

```
     for(;;){
          pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
          if(fifo_queue[i] == NULL)  {
                  pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mut);
                  fetch_all_element();
          }
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
      }
```

but in this way, I need to create N condition variables and mutexes, for N threads.
Is it resource-consuming? 
are there good ways for blocking the thread on this condition until it is satisfied?
thanks!

Comment: If you want to poll, like in the first loop, you should add some type of delay like sleep(1) or whatever delay us suitable so it doesn't hog too much CPU. If you can't tolerate any latency you will want to add some kind of signalling from the writing thread to the reading thread. Maybe a semaphore

Comment: The pthreads library has semaphores. See http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview

Comment: then I still need to create N semaphores? is semaphore more resource-consuming or thread condition variable more time-consuming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a project that sounds very similar to what you are doing. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239864/non-busy-blocking-queue-implementation-in-c/16243249#16243249)

What I did was create a thread safe queue that will block any process trying to dequeue from the queue if it is empty or block a process trying to enqueue if the queue is full. So once an entry is added to the queue, a consuming process will be signaled. This way you are not wasting CPU cycles by polling each thread.

Not sure this necessarily works in your scenario, but it might give you an idea as to how to solve your problem.

**EDIT :** Here is an additional function that might be of use. It returns '1' is the queue is empty. A similar function for isFull() could be created off of this.

```
int isEmpty(Queue *q)
{
    int ret;
    sem_wait(q->excl);
    if (q->count <= 0) 
        ret = 1;
    else 
        ret = 0;
    sem_post(q->excl);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: then I still need to create N semaphores? is semaphore more resource-consuming or thread condition variable more time-consuming?

Comment: @misteryes - That would depend on what you are trying to do in your program. If you are trying to have 1 thread produce entries for the queue and have N threads pulling data from the queue, then you would not need N semaphores. If for some reason you can't have each thread point to the same queue, then you will probably need to have 1 queue for each thread.

Comment: There are N types of entries, each type corresponds to one thread. if I put all entries in one queue. Then how to arrange the data pulling by the N threads?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your thread that fills the queues should signal the other threads when it fills the entire queue.  While the setup of all the condition variables is time consuming, while the program is out of this init period, it should run a lot faster since you won't be wasting CPU time looping with your N threads.  Rather, 1 thread will be running (the main thread that fills up the queues), and then when it has to, it will signal one thread and that one will begin to execute.  Its up to you whether or not the main thread continues to execute, since you may need to add more mutexes in order to make sure the main thread doesn't trample on any other threads.

Comment: I don't get your point. How to signal the other N thread? define N different signals?

Comment: Yeah, you could define N different signals.

Comment: are you sure? aren't there only 2 user defined signals?

Comment: I actually don't know.  I'd have to dig deeper to get an absolute answer.  Basically you want to signal individual threads that have the same method running right?